# Existence of only one bounded linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $X$ a linear normed space over $K$ . $I$ be arbitrary indexing set , $\{f_\alpha: \alpha \in I\}\subset X$ and a family $\{c_\alpha: \alpha\in I\} \subset K$, I want to know that there exists exactly one bounded linear functional $f'\in X'$ with

- $f'(f)=c_\alpha\quad \mbox{ for all}\quad \alpha  \in I$
- $||f||\le M\quad \mbox{ for some}\quad M\geq 0$

exists when for every finite subfamily $J \subset I$ and every choice of the member $\{\beta_\alpha :\alpha \in J\} \subset K$ the following inequality holds:
$$\left|\sum_{\alpha \in J}\beta_\alpha c_\alpha\right|\le M\left\|\sum_{\alpha\in J} \beta_\alpha f_\alpha\right\|_X$$
I have been trying to solve this problem , to be frank i don't understand the question fully , I need a big deal of help to solve and understand this problem . Thank you very much .

Comment: Are the $f_\alpha$ linearly independent? And $J$ assumed finite?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : As per question i found , it says nothing about the dependency of $f_\alpha$ , but yes $J$ is finite .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\{f_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ are linearly independent. Consider $X_0=\mathrm{span}\{f_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ and define
$$
f'':X_0\to K: \sum\limits_{\alpha\in I}\beta_\alpha f_\alpha\mapsto \sum\limits_{\alpha\in I}\beta_\alpha c_\alpha f_\alpha
$$
Take arbitrary $x\in X_0$, then $x=\sum\limits_{\alpha\in J}\beta_\alpha f_\alpha$ for some finite $J\subset I$ and $\{\beta_\alpha:\alpha\in J\}\subset K$. In this case
$$
|f''(x)|=
\left|f''\left(\sum\limits_{\alpha\in J}\beta_\alpha f_\alpha\right)\right|=
\left|\sum\limits_{\alpha\in J}\beta_\alpha c_\alpha\right|\leq
M\left\Vert \sum\limits_{\alpha\in J}\beta_\alpha f_\alpha\right\Vert=M\Vert x\Vert
$$
Since $x\in X_0$ is arbitrary we conclude that $f''\in  X_0^*$ and $\Vert f''\Vert\leq M$. Then by Hahn-Banach theorem you can extend $f''$ to the $f'\in X^*$ with $\Vert f'\Vert\leq M$ and $f'|_{X_0}=f''$. In this case $f'(f_\alpha)=f''(f_\alpha)=c_\alpha$, so we have built the desired functional $f'$.

Comment: Can you give me more explanation , and comments about the steps that u have written .

Comment: @Theorem see my edits

Comment: Thank you, i will let you know if i have some confusion.  Is the extension always unique , normally when i see hahn banach extension theorem , its not stated ?

Comment: It is not unique in general. Uniqueness is equivalent to non existence of segment in the unit sphere of dual space.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the existence of the unique linear functional as above without using the last given inequality?

Comment: The question seems to be different , i think i have to prove that the functional exists and then from that show the last inequality . Does that make sense ?

Comment: No it doesn't. In this case there are some values of $c_\alpha$ when $f'$ is unbounded